# Keras ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 48, 48, 96) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a dataset which I'm trying to train using Keras but every time i get this error: "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 48, 48, 96) are incompatible" and I can't figure it out what's wrong. I read other related questions but couldn't understand the core of my problem

```
DATASET_PATH = "/Users/user/Documents/ML Projects/Dataset"
CLASSNAME_SIZE = 96
IMG_SIZE = 48


#Creating Dictionary of Classname

with open(JSON_PATH) as classnameJSON:
    CLASSNAME = json.loads(classnameJSON.read())

trainingData = []
X = []
Y = []


#loading data

def loadTrainingData():
    for instance in range(CLASSNAME_SIZE):
        joinedPath = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, str(instance))
        label = str(instance)
        for img in os.listdir(joinedPath):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(joinedPath,img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                trainingData.append([new_array, label])
            except Exception as err:
                pass

loadTrainingData()
print(len(trainingData))

def distributeTrainingData():
    for img, label in trainingData:
        X.append(img)
        Y.append(label)


distributeTrainingData()
print("distributing data")
X = np.array(X, dtype='float32')
Y = np.array(Y, dtype='float32')
print(len(X))
print(len(Y))

def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(CLASSNAME_SIZE, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = cnn_model()


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, you need to decide whether you want to one-hot encode your targets and use `categorical_crossentropy` loss, or pass them as 1D tensor and use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss.

You are passing them as 1D tensor while using `categorical_crossentropy` loss. These two are incompatible. Easy fix for you is to change the loss to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Second issue is that you are passing 3D tensor (image) to Dense layer which expects a flat input. If you don't want to use convolutional layers (and even if), you will need to flatten the input before passing it to the Dense layers. You can use `keras.layers.Flatten()` for that.

So, change `compile` method to

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and add `Flatten` layer to your model.

```
def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(CLASSNAME_SIZE, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = cnn_model()
```

In case you want to add some convolutional (`keras.layers.Conv2D`) layers before dense layers, the `Flatten` layer will be added between the convolutional base and the dense top.

```
def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(...))
    # ... more conv/pool layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(CLASSNAME_SIZE, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you add the Dense layers, try adding:

```python
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
```